# TextField Blocked when option "Sin Asignar" is selected

Tags: javascript

Morning.

Ive got a problem in JS , and i dont know how to solve it. As you can see in the image below, my textfield is blocked when I press the option "Sin Asignar " in other combobox. I show you the code:

```
if($("#presupuestoProyectoNew").val() == 0){
                $("#clientesProyectoNew").multiselect("enable");
                $("#tarifasProyectoNew").multiselect("enable");
                $("#clientesProyectoNew").multiselect("refresh");
                $("#tarifasProyectoNew").multiselect("refresh");
            }
```

Well, as you can see in the code , when the other combobox his value is 0. The others combobox are blocked. This part is doing his work fine. However, I cant understand why the textfield is blocked, i cant write anything. Why its happening this? Anyone can help? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally i found the answer.

```
if($("#presupuestoProyectoNew").val() == 0){
                $("#clientesProyectoNew").multiselect("enable");
                $("#tarifasProyectoNew").multiselect("enable");
                $("#clientesProyectoNew").multiselect("refresh");
                $("#tarifasProyectoNew").multiselect("refresh");
                //down there
                $(':input').prop('disabled', false);
            }
```

With this line up, i can control the input text , making it enabled when get inside the  if condition .